# Django Resize image in Forms

Tags: django, resize, python-imaging-library

I'm using python 3.6 and Django 2.0.

I have a square image that I want uploaded to a model. I currently have an image field in a model that I can upload.

```
avatar             = models.ImageField(path_and_rename, max_length=255, blank=True
```

I want to resize whatever square image is uploaded to be 750 by 750. I thought of a way to do it, but I don't think I'm saving it as the right type as it is giving me an error.

```
'Image' object has no attribute '_committed'
```

How can I resize my square image to meet the new dimensions that I need.

My code (leaving out validation to make it simpler):

forms.py

```
def clean_avatar(self):
  avatar = self.cleaned_data['avatar']
  try:
    print(len(avatar))
    w, h = get_image_dimensions(avatar)
    max_width = max_height = 750
    image = Image.open(avatar)
    resized_image = image.resize((max_width,max_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    print(type(avatar))
    print(type(image))
    print(type(resized_image))
    return resized_image
  except
    ...
```

the output of the above is

```
<class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'>
<class 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'>
<class 'PIL.Image.Image'>
```

if I return `avatar` it works, but it doesnt' work when I return `resized_image`. How can I make the datatype of `resized_image` that of `avatar`?

Full error message:

```
File "C:\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner


35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py" in dispatch
  52.         return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  194.         return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  142.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "C:\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in form_valid
  125.         self.object = form.save()

File "C:\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in save
  456.             self.instance.save()

File "C:\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py" in save
  73.         super().save(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  729.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "C:\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  759.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "C:\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  820.                       for f in non_pks]

File "C:\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in <listcomp>
  820.                       for f in non_pks]

File "C:\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in pre_save
  285.         if file and not file._committed:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /account/details/
Exception Value: 'Image' object has no attribute '_committed'
```

Comment: DO you want to resize image automatically or you want to give user the option which part of the image they want to choose?

Comment: `Image.open` returns a `PIL.Image.Image` object from (presumably) a `str` object which is a file name. What you probably need is to create a file using `.save` with a suitable `str` as a temporary name and then pass that.

Comment: @BidhanMajhi I have some react code that will let the user crop the photo as they desire. Then I want to have them upload it where it will then be resized.

Comment: @Kapil do I save it in the forms section or do I save else (the view?)

Answer (score 0):

I have done simillar thing, but not in forms. My approach was like this:

```
# override Model Save Method

class YourModel(models.Model):
  ...
  def save(self, **kwargs):
     resize = kwargs.pop('resize', False)
     instance = super(YourModel, self).save(**kwargs)
     if resize:
        pil_image = Image.open(self.avatar.path)
        # resize related code
        resized_image = pil_image.resize((max_width,max_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        resized_image.save(self.avatar.path)

     return instance
```

And call this save method from form like this:

```
 class YourForm(...):
     ...
     def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(YourForm, self).save(commit=False)
        instance.save(resize=True)  # call model save method from here
        return instance
```

#### Update

Maybe you can try like this:

```
import io 

# clean method
w, h = get_image_dimensions(avatar)
max_width = max_height = 750
image = Image.open(avatar)
resized_image = image.resize((max_width,max_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img_in_memory = io.BytesIO()
resized_image.save(img_in_memory, format="png")
return img_in_memory
```

Comment: I tried this and for this line `pil_image = Image.open(self.avatar.path)` I got an error message - `this back end doesn't support absolute paths`. I'm using s3 to save my files. Gonna look into this tomorrow.

Comment: I saw another post say to change it to self.avatar.name, but when I do it says that the file doesn't exist (cause I haven't saved it yet). Confusing.

Comment: @MicahPearce please see my answer's update section. Hope it helps!!